# Unknown provider: $translateStaticFilesLoaderProvider <- $translateStaticFilesLoader

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-translate

I have been trying to use angular-translate with a static JSON file, usign StaticFilesLoader. However, I recieve the error:
`Unknown provider: $translateStaticFilesLoaderProvider <- $translateStaticFilesLoader`

In the index.html file, i have included the .js files:

```
    <script src="js/i18n/angular-translate.js"></script>
    <script src="js/i18n/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js"></script>
    <script src="js/i18n/angular-translate-loader-static-files.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/i18n/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
```

I have included the directive   `'pascalprecht.translate'`

And I have also included the config in the app.js file:

```
    Application.instance
        .config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
            $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
                prefix: 'i18n/',
                suffix: '.json'
            });

    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
}]);
```

If I include the translations directly in the config, the angular-translate works fine, but it seems that the staticFilesLoader is the issue. I have replaced the angular-translate-loader-static-files.js files from github and this does not resolve the issue.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding angular-translate twice, minified and unminified (judging by names)

But the error you get is mostlikely caused by not injecting the module to your module

```
var Application = angular.module('myApplication', ['pascalprecht.translate'])
```

Comment: Update: by removing the duplicate angular-translate link, the unknown provider error has been resolved, but the file does not translate, it just shows the key word - e.g. {{ 'TITLE' | translate }} shows as TITLE on the page?

Comment: Is it loading the `en.json` file? check the NET tab of developer tools

Comment: It loads the en.json file, however I had the key values in single quotes instead of double. Got it going now, seems that the duplicate angular-translate link was the main issue. Thanks!